# Why is there a fixed block size write after importing data using mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, linux, performance, io

When I am using mysqldump to import data, I exec `pidstat -p ${pid of mysqld} -d 2` .
Then I saw that after executing mysqldump, there are still fixed-size blocks written. I think it is amazing. Why is this phenomenon?

[image]

Comment: The server is probably using buffered writing to the socket.

Answer (score 0):

A guess:  Writes are buffered through the buffer_pool.  After the busy part ended, the buffer_pool was mostly full and 'dirty'.  After that, a background task flushed the blocks at its leisure, apparently at a rate of about 6MB/s